# assign values ​to an armadillo matrix

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am learning c ++ and I need to use matrices. I found the armadillo library but I cannot assign values ​​to the array in the same way as seen in the example. https://github.com/lsolanka/armadillo/blob/master/examples/example1.cpp (line 41)

For example to the following code

```cpp
mat FLat(5,5), BLat(5,1), HLat(1,5), QLat(5,5), RLat(1,1);

Flat << -14.929 << 0 << -1 <<0.194<<0 <<endr
     <<3920.814<<-15.634<<1.282<<0<<0 <<endr
     <<-36.818<< -0.352<<-0.141<< 0<<0 <<endr
     <<0<<1<<0<<0<<0 <<endr
      <<0<<0<<0.696<<0<<0<<endr;
```

I get the error "error: ‘Flat’ does not name a type"

Comment: Variable identifiers are case sensitive. Did you mean `FLat` instead of `Flat`?

Comment: If you are leaning C++ and you need to use matricies -- why on earth would you look at something like armadillo? That will teach you nothing about using either (1) a 2D array; (2) allocating for a number of pointers-to-1D arrays; or (3 preferred) using a vector-of-vectors. Learn C++ before looking at specialized libraries somebody else has written.

Comment: sorry, I just noticed that it works but inside the main. Maybe it's because I'm new, but why can't I instantiate this type of variable globally?